# Are the episodes of The Terror (TV series) in chronological order or do they follow the order of the book via flashbacks?

Tags: tv, suggested-order, dan-simmons

I'm reading [The Terror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terror_(novel)), but also want to see the [TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terror_(TV_series)).

The book is really captivating me, and I'm really eager to watch the series too. Clearly I could finish reading the book first, but if the series has the same sequence of times shown in the book, then I could watch each episode after I've read the corresponding chapters in the book.